# How to set variable for each request for apollo-client?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I'm using apollo-client and want to send some variable for each request. Let's call it `locale`. I don't want to pass it to every `Query` component, it's not DRY pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using middleware:

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloLink, concat } from 'apollo-link';

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: '/graphql' });

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  operation.setContext({
    headers: {
      locale: localStorage.getItem('locale') || 'en-US',
    }
  });

  return forward(operation);
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
});
```

Checkout the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/network-layer/

Answer (score -1):

You can add a middleware link, which will be modifying your `operation` on fly

```
  class MiddlewareLink extends ApolloLink {
    request (operation: Operation, forward: NextLink) {
      operation.variables['prop1'] = 'value1'

      return forward(operation)
    }
  }

  ...
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: ApolloLink.from([
      new MiddlewareLink(),
      httpLink
    ])
  })
```

This way looks like the most correct right now, maybe later `apollo-link-http` will be extended and will be able to accept some data from the context and pass to variables.